# using strings and ints together in c

Tags: c

c# version :

```
text_layer_set_text(hello_layer, "Last:"+x+" min");
```

c ( for pebble[Programmable Watch] )  version:

```
 text_layer_set_text(&hello_layer, **WHAT SHOULD I PUT HERE?**);
```

I Also Saw This :

> sprintf and friends require malloc, which isn't supported in the
> watchface SDK. They're also *massive* functions that'll far exceed the
> available space for a Pebble app.
>
> 'd recommend trying something like a hand-rolled itoa implementation.
> Any itoa that avoids dynamically allocated memory should do the trick.
> Also, you should be able to simplify your implementation if you're
> only interested in printing numbers in Base 10.

Comment: Have you considered a C-tutorial?

Comment: i tried using sprintf, that was what i used all the time, but it doenst work on my device. Im actually a c++ coder not c so im just trying to find another ways since i cant use sprint f

Comment: @user2596732 You have to include stdio.h

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `sprintf` to concatenate strings/ints like this:

```
 char buffer[100];
 sprintf(buffer, "Last:%d min", x);
 text_layer_set_text(&hello_layer, buffer);
```

**Edit:**

For Pebble there seems to be a header `mini-printf.h` that defines `mini_snprintf`. So give this a try:

```
#include "mini-printf.h"

mini_snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "Last:%d min", x);
```

Comment: If there is another way i will kindly accept , it just said : Build failed, i put the full error to the topic

Comment: @user2596732 What is the prototype for `text_layer_set_text`? I just assumed `text_layer_set_text(whatever type &hello_layer is, char *)`

Comment: @user2596732 You probably haven't included stdio.h

Comment: I did saw something like this : sprintf and friends require malloc, which isn't supported in the watchface SDK. They're also _massive_ functions that'll far exceed the available space for a Pebble app.'d recommend trying something like a hand-rolled itoa implementation. Any itoa that avoids dynamically allocated memory should do the trick. Also, you should be able to simplify your implementation if you're only interested in printing numbers in Base 10.

Comment: @user2596732 There seems to be a `mini_snprintf` function for pebble. Check my edit.